# How to specify a git commit message template for a repository in a file at a relative path to the repository?

Tags: git

Is there a way to specify a git commit.template that is relative to a repository?

For configuration an example is

```
$ git config commit.template $HOME/.gitmessage.txt
```

But I would like to specify a template file relative to the .git folder of the repository.

Comment: Note: for those that want relative to home, `git config commit.template ~/.gitmessage.txt` is documented to work on `man` as of 1.9, and would be preferable to using `$HOME`, as you could use the same file even if you change username.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[This blog](http://www.syntevo.com/blog/?p=4076) tipped me off that if the path to the template file is not absolute, then the path is considered to be relative to the repository root.

```
git config commit.template /absolute/path/to/file

or

git config commit.template relative-path-from-repository-root
```

Answer (score 22):

I used the prepare-commit-msg hook to solve this.

First create a file `.git/commit-msg` with the template of the commit message like

```
$ cat .git/commit-msg
My Commit Template
```

Next create a file `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` with the contents

```
#!/bin/sh

firstLine=$(head -n1 $1)

if [ -z "$firstLine"  ] ;then
    commitTemplate=$(cat `git rev-parse --git-dir`/commit-msg)
    echo -e "$commitTemplate\n $(cat $1)" > $1
fi
```

Mark the newly-created file as executable:

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
```

This sets the commit message to the contents of the template.

Answer (score 8):

You can always specify a template at commit-time with `-t <file>` or `--template=<file>`.

See: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit

Another option might be to use a `prepare-commit-msg` hook: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3525532/289099

Answer (score 5):

**1. Create a file with your custom template inside your project directory.**

In this example in the `.git/` folder of the project :

```
$ cat << EOF > .git/.commit-msg-template
> My custom template
> # Comment in my template
> EOF
```

**2. Edit the `config` file in the `.git/` folder of your project to add the path to your custom template.**

- With *git* command :

  ```
  $ git config commit.template .git/.commit-msg-template
  ```
- Or by adding in the *config* file the following lines :

  ```
  [commit]
    template = .git/.commit-msg-template
  ```

Et voilà !