# BitBucket - How is the pull request description field used when merging a PR?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-log

We are using Bitbucket at work, here is the UI for creating a new commit message/description when doing a merge via pull request:

[image]

as you can see in the screenshot, the question is: 
where does the data from the description text box go?

In other words, I am using this command to capture select data from the git log:

```
git log -30 --pretty=format:'{"commit":"%H","sanitized_subject_line":"%f","commit_notes":"%N","author":"%aN","date":"%aD"}'
```

Is there a way to capture the data from the description textbox in the UI? What is that textbox for?

Comment: That's the long form of the commit message.

Comment: got it - as opposed to the "sanitized_subject_line"?

Comment: do you know how to change bitbucket so that there is a default message in the description textbox?

Comment: As the answer points out, the UI you are showing is not for commits in the first place.

Comment: ummm @MadPhysicist I am not convinced of that...surely those text fields are for creating the message for the merge commit.

Comment: There is a difference between merge commit and pull request, even when they go hand-in-hand on most occasions.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this Title and Description, is specific to the Pull Request itself. It has nothing to do with a commit so it won't appear in the git log.

Comment: Unless it's 1 commit, then the description will be whatever is after the first sentence in the commit message.

Comment: My answer still stands. In that case, BitBucket is just taking the Title and Description from the single commit and pre-populating the Title and Description of the Pull Request with it, as a matter of convenience.

Comment: @JamieBisotti thanks for your answer - do you know if there is any way whatsover to alter/create a git commit message or the commit_notes field in the git log via the Bitbucket UI? I want my team to create their "important" commit messages through the UI when they submit a PR.

Comment: Looks like you cannot currently specify a PR template -- https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/11571/custom-pull-request-description-template. However, you can specify a commit template for Git clients to use -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998728/how-to-specify-a-git-commit-message-template-for-a-repository-in-a-file-at-a-rel -- not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: n.b. that screenshot is from Bitbucket Server, not Bitbucket Cloud.

Comment: I just added an answer, as I hope, it looks like you can add / update the git commit message for the PR, it was just in a later stage of the process in the UI.

Comment: As has been pointed out a couple of different times, there is no "git commit message for the PR". Git commits have messages, which can be formatted as a subject line, followed by a space, followed by a body. PRs have titles and descriptions. PRs are not commits; their title/description does not become part of Git's history. When you merge, a "merge commit" is created; this is an actual Git commit; it has nothing to do with a PR.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you add to the commit message *after you click the merge button* on the Bitbucket UI:

[image]

This should be the place in the UI where you can craft a specific git message that matches some pattern so that you can search for that pattern later with `git log` etc.

Comment: This does not answer the question you actually asked.

Comment: but won't this appear in the git commit log?

Comment: @AlexanderMills -- did you enable a setting to have bitbucket add the commit message edit field? Our bitbucket server is not showing this edit field.