# change template for commit message in vs code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, editor, commit, commit-message

Im am using VS Code to write commit messages. When I type `git commit -a` VS Code starts up with this text:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch assi
# Changes to be committed:
#   modified:   Default_Navigation.cs
#
```

is it possible to change this template?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify a git commit message template for a repository in a file at a relative path to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998728/how-to-specify-a-git-commit-message-template-for-a-repository-in-a-file-at-a-rel)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+commit+template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`git config commit.template /absolute/path/to/template_file` seems to be the way to go. Check out [How to specify a git commit message template for a repository in a file at a relative path to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998728/how-to-specify-a-git-commit-message-template-for-a-repository-in-a-file-at-a-rel)