# What is VS Code's "new git grammar" in the v1.76 release notes?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw this in the v1.76 release notes of VS Code:

Git commit syntax highlighting:
[image: Git commit syntax highlighting]

What is meant by "new Git grammar"?

I want to define some git commit rules for my company. Rules build on VS Codes git grammer respectivly the syntax hightlighting of git commit messages may be a good idea?!

Comment: "(...) which provides syntax highlighting" - how does this relate to the rules you want to define?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/173195 looks like the commit responsible for this release note section

Answer (score 1):

The release notes being referred to are here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_76#_git-commit-syntax-highlighting.

The relevant issue ticket is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/3876.

The commit that implemented it is here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/cc226c05816dbc1b58260486eed72b83642ec63d.

The git grammar provides syntax highlighting for the commit and rebase message templates that git provides (and that you can configure (see [How to specify a git commit message template for a repository in a file at a relative path to the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21998728/11107541))) for editing commit messages, and which VS Code presents to you when you want to commit and your `git.useEditorAsCommitInput` is `true` (which it is by default if you don't set it to anything).

(Example template that you might have seen something like before):

> ```
> # Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
> # with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
> #
> # On branch main
> #
> # Initial commit
> #
> # Changes to be committed:
> # new file:   bar/bar.js
> # new file:   foo.js
> #
> # Changes not staged for commit:
> # modified:   foo.js
> #
> # Untracked files:
> # .vscode/
> # index.html
> #
> ```